# Hidden value not being submitted

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I am trying everything I can think of to pass a PHP variable to Javascript and back to PHP as the code will hopefully show. The output from the script is always '9' and I cannot determine why.

```
<script>
function changeContent3(func){
    <?php if (isset($_POST['userid'])) {
        $userid=$_POST['userid'];
    } else {
        $userid=9;
    } ?>
    if (func=='12') {message = "<?php SignUpForm($userid); ?>";}
    document.getElementById('content2').innerHTML = message;
}
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="include/layout.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<div id="floater"></div>
<div id="centeredinv">
<div id="centered1">
    <div id="content2">
    <div class='FMblock'>
        <div class="FMcells">
            <CENTER><form method="post"><input type='hidden' name='userid' value='1'><a class="udlinks" onclick="changeContent3('12');"><i>one</i></CENTER></a></form>
        </div>
        <div class="FMcells">
            <CENTER><form method="post"><input type='hidden' name='userid' value='2'><a class="udlinks" onclick="changeContent3('12');"><i>two</i></CENTER></a></form>
        </div>
        <div class="FMcells">
            <CENTER><form method="post"><input type='hidden' name='userid' value='3'><a class="udlinks" onclick="changeContent3('12');"><i>three</i></CENTER></a></form>
        </div>
        <div class="FMcells">
            <CENTER><form method="post"><input type='hidden' name='userid' value='4'><a class="udlinks" onclick="changeContent3('12');"><i>four</i></CENTER></a></form>
        </div>
        <div class="FMcells">
            <CENTER><form method="post"><input type='hidden' name='userid' value='5'><a class="udlinks" onclick="changeContent3('12');"><i>five</i></CENTER></a></form>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>  
<?php
function SignUpForm($userid) {
echo"YAY ".$userid;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Will one of those forms ever be submitted?

Comment: I had hoped the value would be carried with the onClick

Comment: `onClick` not equals `submit`

Comment: Then I am sorry to destroy your hope. For PHP to access via `$_POST`, a form needs to be submitted (that means the site refreshes if no other action is defined). Also this mix of JavaScript and PHP doesn't look healthy, I'd suggest rewriting it, using AJAX probably would be a nice solution

Comment: Ok so is there a way to make a submit that doesn't look like a submit? I'm trying to avoid turn the onClick into a button for visual appeal reasons

Comment: this is actually only one portion of the page I'm displaying and the goal is to only update this section and not the entire page. I have tried in AJAX but my brain cant wrap around it.

Comment: what's with the `<center>` tag?...is deprecated, use css

Comment: this is only a sample. the CSS is all set for the real script and <center> is not even remotely an issue to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very elegant, but you can try something like below.
In my sample, "one" has no userid so it will take 9. Others have a userid.

Edit : there was a bug in my previous code

```
<script>
function changeContent3(func,func2){
    userid = func2;
    if(!userid) {
        userid = 9;
    }
    if (func=='12') {message = "YAY " + userid;}
    document.getElementById('content2').innerHTML = message;
}
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="include/layout.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<div id="floater"></div>
<div id="centeredinv">
<div id="centered1">
    <div id="content2">
    <div class='FMblock'>
        <div class="FMcells">
            <CENTER><form method="post"><input type='hidden' name='userid' value='' id="a"><a class="udlinks" onclick="changeContent3('12', + document.getElementById('a').value);"><i>one</i></CENTER></a></form>
        </div>
        <div class="FMcells">
            <CENTER><form method="post"><input type='hidden' name='userid' value='2' id="b"><a class="udlinks" onclick="changeContent3('12', + document.getElementById('b').value);"><i>two</i></CENTER></a></form>
        </div>
        <div class="FMcells">
            <CENTER><form method="post"><input type='hidden' name='userid' value='3' id="c"><a class="udlinks" onclick="changeContent3('12', + document.getElementById('c').value);"><i>three</i></CENTER></a></form>
        </div>
        <div class="FMcells">
            <CENTER><form method="post"><input type='hidden' name='userid' value='4' id="d"><a class="udlinks" onclick="changeContent3('12' , + document.getElementById('d').value);"><i>four</i></CENTER></a></form>
        </div>
        <div class="FMcells">
            <CENTER><form method="post"><input type='hidden' name='userid' value='5' id="e"><a class="udlinks" onclick="changeContent3('12' , + document.getElementById('e').value);"><i>five</i></CENTER></a></form>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works perfectly but how do I get the userid as a variable for the php function SignUpForm($userid) {echo"YAY ".$userid;}

Comment: I have edited my code because there was a little bug. With my code you don't need a php function anymore. Do you really need one ? and why ?

Comment: I assume I need one to display the mysql data about the userid. Each of the userid has its own MySQL data such as username. It is this information that will be displayed after the onClick

Comment: Well ok...i think you should review all your approach, but i have edited my answer to add a code that uses your PHP function

Comment: my new code was bugous, i have removed it, i rewrite it wait a little

Comment: No way to rewrite it this way as we cannot pass js variable to PHP. You should review your approach by posting your forms.
Explain more precisely what you are trying to do and i will write a more suitable entire code

Comment: That is what I was trying to accomplish in my original code, to pass the userid as a POST but it always came up blank and resorted to userid equalling 9

Answer (score 0):

Here a sample code to guide you.
Three has no userid, others have.
All this code stand in a single page named test.php.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>stack</title>
</head>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['userid']) && $_POST['userid'] != "") {
    $userid=$_POST['userid'];
} else {
    $userid = 9;
}
?>
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="test.php"><input type='hidden' name='userid' value='1'><a href="#" onclick="document.forms['form1'].submit();">one</a></form>
<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="test.php"><input type='hidden' name='userid' value='2'><a href="#" onclick="document.forms['form2'].submit();">two</a></form>
<form id="form3" name="form3" method="post" action="test.php"><input type='hidden' name='userid' value=''><a href="#" onclick="document.forms['form3'].submit();">three</a></form>
<div id="content2"><?php echo $userid; ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```